# Ubuntu Goes to Black Screen After Any Chosen Grub Options

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 13.10

I am new to Ubuntu and I have tried everything that I can think of.  I have Windows 8 and I wanted to try Ubuntu.  But, when I boot to my USB, it shows my GRUB options, "Try without installing" "Install" "OEM Install" and "Boot-Repair".  When I choose any one of these options, it doesn't work at all, it just goes to a black screen and stays there.  I checked if my graphics card was not compatible, but it is fully compatible.  I don't know what to do now.

I have a Toshiba Satellite C855D-S5100 with Windows 8.1 Pro installed with Secure Boot and Fast Boot off.

This USB Flash drive was made by the site standards with the 64-bit iso put on the formatted flash drive using the site specified application.

I have also tried this on my family's desktop and it runs perfectly first try via my USB flash drive, I just can't use that computer for Ubuntu because the HDD is completely full.

Can somebody please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has some known issues with Windows 8 computers (more specifically, with the UEFI Bootloader..) even though it gets advertised as being compatible. Can you try turning UEFI off in your bios, and then try again with installing?

Here is a link with instructions how to do so: http://bhaismachine.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/how-to-disable-uefi-and-dual-boot-ubuntu-and-windows-on-an-uefi-enabled-laptop/

Answer (score 0):

I know for my computer, all I had to do was simply turn the brightness up on the Laptop. I felt really stupid because I downloaded the ISO 3 times to try to fix it. It might be a simple of a fix as that, seeing as it works on your family computer.